# Embed video in github pages doesn't display any thing

Tags: html, web, github, video, github-pages

I'm using GitHub pages and I have an issue with embeding videos: the video dispkay an error message when I click play and below my html code:

```
<div class="row video">
   <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{% "eBzTCbGnlWo" %}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
       allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Please help me to solve this issue, below is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try using `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eBzTCbGnlWo` because those `{%` etc symbols are invalid characters for an iFrame URL. Why are you using them? (_eg:_ is it needed that way?).

Comment: Hi! thank you for replaying, but I already test it and it's the same, normally github doesn't accept videos, I thought that just for README.md but I think it's a concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that the `readme.md` itself cannot have embedded videos but a `GitHub.io` page  is allowed to. Here I have an old [video example](https://vcone.github.io/public/demos/Mpeg_TS/VC1_Demo_LO_01.html) still working today, proving that GitHub does allow videos.

**Solution**:

Replace your line:

```
<iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{% "eBzTCbGnlWo" %}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

With this modified version:

```
<iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LgWX2sPZQsE/" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```